# laravel moving query out of controller

Tags: php, sql, laravel

In my controller, I have produced a couple of queries, both very similar in what data they select from the same table, one I have pagination on and the other returns values based on what someone searches for.

Both queries start with $data = equipment::DB('...leftjoin...leftjoin...leftjoin, one ends with paginate(15) and the other ends with where(...). Both work great, however as i understand it, a controller is designed to direct traffic and not to be quering the data.

```
$equipment = DB::table('equipment')->select('equipment.id','UnitNo','Description', 'SerialNo','Make','Model','SiteName','Year')
    ->leftJoin('sites', 'site_id', '=', 'sites.id')
        ->leftJoin('makes', 'make_id', '=', 'makes.id')
            ->leftJoin('models', 'model_id', '=', 'models.id')
    ->orderBy($this->sortcol,$this->direction)
        //->get()
        ->paginate(15);



    $this->layout->content = View::make('equipment.index')
        ->with('equipment', $equipment)
        ->with('sortcol', $this->sortcol)
        ->with('direction', $this->direction)
        ->with('page', $this->page);   //, compact('equipment'));
```

I want to reduce the size of my controller and refactor this code so it is more reusable.

Can I simply set up a function in the model that returns the first part of the data and then add the final parts to the end, for example:

Controller:
$data = Equipment::modelFunction()-paginate(15)

Model:

```
public function modelFunction(){
return DB::table('equipment')->select('equipment.id','UnitNo','Description',   'SerialNo','Make','Model','SiteName','Year')
->leftJoin('sites', 'site_id', '=', 'sites.id')
    ->leftJoin('makes', 'make_id', '=', 'makes.id')
        ->leftJoin('models', 'model_id', '=', 'models.id')

}
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: yup....................

Comment: I'd go with Services+Repositories and not pollute the Model. Then you can inject those services into your controllers. Models should only describe your business entities and relations. (http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers)

Comment: Repository patterns and service providers.   [Guide here](http://autonomousdev.com/blog/2)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'm not quite yet at this stage of laravel being pretty new to it, I will read up on this and try a few examples to try and get my head around this concept.

Comment: Please read [this book](https://leanpub.com/laravel) by Taylor Otwell, the creator of Laravel. The techniques (Repository pattern, SOLID design principles and Dependency Injection) he covers are nothing new, however he frames them in a Laravel context and provides an efficient primer on their use. Covering and using the techniques used here will **really** help you in the long run!

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I will make the investment